# Zoom to a collection of graphics in ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.x

Tags: zoom, graphics, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Im trying to zoom to the extent of a couple of graphics that are on the map. None of the methods that worked for api 3.x are available in v4. Im hoping someone knows alternatives.

> https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/functionality-matrix/index.html

graphicsUtils is marked as coming soon. This has the **graphicsExtent(graphics)** method that i could use.

I have tried the method

```
view.goTo()
```

but I need to specify the zoom myself. Which is not helpful. I want it to dynamically calculate bounds/extent and zoom to fit the graphics.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var fullExtent = null;
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    if (!fullExtent)
        fullExtent = features[i].geometry.extent.clone();
    else
        fullExtent.union(features[i].geometry.extent)
}
mapView.goTo(fullExtent).then(function () {
    if (!mapView.extent.contains(fullExtent))
        mapView.zoom -= 1;
});
```

That is my ugly solution for now because the goTo() function doesn't have a fit parameter.
BTW, You can also try using something like fullExtent.expand(1.5) instead of adjusting the zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

The [view.goTo()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#goTo) method seems to work fine for zooming to an array of graphics.  As Orlando has shown, you can zoom out one level to create a cushion.

```
view.goTo(graphics).then(function () {
    view.zoom = view.zoom - 1;
});
```